# Android Send Mail with pdf

Tags: android, email, pdf, permissions, email-attachments

In My Application I download PDF file to internal storage. after this  I want to send mail with the file. I see the file is dowloaded in internal memory
com.my.app  -> files-> pdffile.pdf
and it has permissions -rw-------

when I attach to mail the file and send gmail says: could't send attachment. But why ?? I have permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this is code for dowloading file. it runs in async task

```
public static boolean saveFile(String fileName, Context context){
    String fileDirectory = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            + "//"+fileName;
    String urlServ = Constants.serverUrl+ "upload/forms/"+fileName;
    urlServ = urlServ.replace(" ", "%20");
    urlServ = urlServ.replace("\n", "%0d");
    urlServ = urlServ.replace("\"", "%22"); 


    int count;
    URI fUri = URI.create("file://" + fileDirectory);
    File f  = new File(fileDirectory);
    if (f.exists()){
        f.delete();
    }


    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlServ);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileDirectory);


        //OutputStream output = context.openFileOutput(fileDirectory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is code for sending mail :

```
public static void sendMail(Context context, String filename) {
    String fileDirectory = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
            + "/"+filename;
    File f  = new File(fileDirectory);
    Uri URI =Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"mytestmail@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);

    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
    try {
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }               
}
```

What is wrong ? it sands mail only with subject and text... maybe there is some permissions issue. How can I donwload file and give it full permissions

EDIT:

It is permission issue, because when I send file with different permission from the same directory, mail with attachment is being sent.  -rw-rw-rw- with this permission

How Can i donwload file and set -rw-rw-rw- permission to it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, if anyone faces the same issue. When opening OutputStream like this
it gives new file permission -rw-rw-rw. and other application(Gmail in this case) can use it.

```
OutputStream output = context.openFileOutput( fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that although your app has permissions to read the file, the email application doesn't have permission to read the file.  Since Jelly Bean, StrictMode has produced a warning when you try to share a File URI outside your application because this kind of problem can occur where the app you are sharing a file with does not have permission to access the file.  It is advised to use a `content://` URI when sharing files between apps instead of a `file://` URI.

I'd suggest using the [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) class, which provides a relatively simple way to share your files using a `content://` URI.